# Storing XAML in a database?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

So the user will create objects a runtime and then type whatever information they want into the Text boxes. Then when they click save the Stackpanel that that they are all wrapped around needs to be saved into a database and when they load that page up again everything appears and they can edit the data inside the textbox.

**Does anyone know of any guides on the internet as ive searched and unfortunately been unsuccessful?**

**Or can someone tell me the way i can get around completing the task?**

Comment: maybe try looking for xaml serialization

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the link please to save the layout. But for the insertion in database I could suggest you to only save the address of the file, not the XAML content.

If you just want to save the values then there's no need to save the object you can just save the layout.

https://web.archive.org/web/20130905043235/https://channel9.msdn.com/Forums/TechOff/WPF-Persisting-window-position-size-theme-and-layout-Saving-to-xml-and-application-settings

Comment: So everytime the user saves a new Stackpanel, a new file has to be created? Is it no possible to save it as a string in a database table?

Comment: It is possible but would be an extra burden on data base normally when we have to save files(text,image, or any other) the best practice is to store the address. It basically consumes less space, but if you still want to store it in a database you can but not a good practice.

Comment: @ Umar Iqbal But when they save, would it create a new file everytime? so it there was 1000 people that created a new view there would be 1000 files?

Comment: It sounds to me like saving the XAML is a mistake in itself, why not simply save the contents of the textbox to the database?

Comment: Yes absolutely, Even 1000 files is fine. Normally there will be less than 1000 users unless you're creating a big commercial software. But you can always save in db if you want.

Comment: In WPF we usually save the layout. Saving the textbox will be difficult to manage.

Comment: @BenjaminPaul Actually sounds like a good idea. Would this be able to load back up? and also would it remember the layout e.g. If the user enters 'Name' in the first box would it show up first?

Comment: @UmarIqbal So your suggestion would be to save the contents of the XAML to a file and save the location into the database, when they click the name of the view they created to load up that file?

Comment: @user3157821 Yes, Absolutely.

Comment: @UmarIqbal Thanks for your suggestion, I am also going to look into this. Do you know of any websites?

Comment: One I've mentioned in my answer else you can search google for ' saving layout in XML ' you'll find a lot of information.

Comment: @UmarIqbal oh sorry I just seen it, thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, I am not attempting to answer this question, but instead merely offering some related advice. In general, we *don't* save UI elements. Those UI elements are made up from properties and it's *those properties* that we save. I don't mean all of the properties, but just the important ones.

For example, if you had a `Canvas` with shapes on it, then you'd need to save the type of shape, the position, size and maybe colour too. With this information, it would be easy to recreate the `Canvas` again at any time.

In your example, you would need to save the data from your `StackPanel`... it sounds as though these are just strings, so all you need to do is to store the string values and maybe their order if that is important. It would be an incredible waste of resources saving the whole `StackPanel` each time as that contains a great many property values that are wholly irrelevant to your requirements.

Comment: Save it into a file using Umar Iqbal way? or into a database?

Comment: Surely, that's up to your requirements, isn't it? Either way, there would be practically no difference to the end user.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to store the xaml content into database so you can use it latter if needed for similar UI.

You can load XAML file as simple file and read the content and save it into database. You can use blob field in case of mysql to store the xaml data. Now whenever you want to use this content to plot design you can read it from database.

Comment: Not for 'Similar UI' i want to be able to load it back up with the users information they entered, so they can edit it. I also need to use SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you really want to save the Xaml?

It sounds like you should have a model for your data and that should be saved to the database. You can then use databinding to create as many `TextBox`es or other controls as required.

If you use an `ItemsControl` instead of a `StackPanel` then you can display a list of items with a text box for each one.

Here is a good tutorial: http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/list-controls/itemscontrol/

Comment: At the moment I am using Databinding and ItemsControl to create the textboxes dynamically. So the user will add the text boxes and add information into the boxes, then i need to save the XAML into the SQL database. Just asking for better solutions ...

Comment: But why do you need to save the XAML, surely you just want to save what's in the textboxes? What if you want to display the information in a Grid in future or some other display format?